# Is the disjunctive normal form unique?

Tags: digital-logic, boolean-algebra, karnaugh-map, function

As the title says, is the DMF always unique? And if no, is there an example of a function that has more than one DMF?

Answer (score 0):

According to the Wikipedia article on DNFs, a Boolean expression can only be expressed by a unique DNF.